# CoreOS on VirtualBox only works with one adapter at a time

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I'm trying to learn more about CoreOS. (I'm not using Vagrant, just plain-old VirtualBox.) So I created a disk using `coreos-install`. Unfortunately, I can't find my original `cloud-config.yaml` file, but it was something simple like this.

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - name: core
    passwd: somehash
    groups:
      - sudo
      - docker
```

After starting the VM, I was able to login with a password. I was also able to `ping google.com`.

However, the next thing I wanted to do was connect to my CoreOS VM from my OS X host. So, I went into my VM's settings > Network and then enabled Adapter 2 as Host-only Adapter. (I had already configured Host-only Networks because I have an Ubuntu VM that I SSH into.)

Anyway, back in CoreOS, I created a file `/etc/systemd/network/10-static.network`. It looks like this.

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s8

[Network]
Address=192.168.56.3/24
Gateway=192.168.56.1
```

I restarted my VM and I was able to SSH into CoreOS from OS X—except that now I couldn't connect to the internet. `ping google.com` failed everytime.

So then, I created another file `/etc/systemd/network/20-dhcp.network`. It looks like this.

```
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

I restarted the VM. I can SSH in from the host, but I can't connect out to the internet.

If I disable my VM's Adapter 2, then I can connect to the internet. However, I can no longer SSH in from the host.

Is there a way to setup the networking so that I can SSH into CoreOS from OS X **and** still connect out to the internet?

Comment: Hey, is your problem solved? I'm also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used the VM Settings->Network->Adaptor 1->Attached = Bridged Adaptor and VM Settings->Network->Adaptor 1->Name = Wi-Fi options and I was able to both ssh in and access the internet from the CoreOS VM

Answer (score 0):

Me too was facing same problem. I gone through docs present at [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd#.5BNetwork.5D). If we didn't specify Gateway option then DHCP is used to route the traffic. So I removed the line `Gateway=192.168.56.1` from `[Network]` section of `static.network` file. And the trick is worked. No need to write `dhcp.network` file. Just reboot the instance and try to ping google.com, you will get responses.
My final file is something like this-
$ cat /etc/systemd/network/static.network

> [Match]
>   Name=enp0s8
>   [Network]
>   Address=192.168.56.102/24
>   DNS=8.8.8.8
>   DNS=8.8.4.4